# Socket Class: Receiving data on windows keeps appending additional data?

Tags: c++, sockets

I've recently written a (dirty, yet working) Socket class for a mininmal purpose.
The class itself works fine so far, except that receiving data will keep appending additional data, however, only on windows. The Additional data is usually something like (replace `$RANDOM_NUMBERS` with random numbers):

```
 TA,guid=$RANDOM_NUMBERS
```

So received Data would look like:

```
received from client: Hello server!TA,guid=dba2ba7f040f9ddb8d7107d800000027
```

While the actual output should be:

```
received from client: Hello server!
```

I've *ported* the BSD Socket Usage as described at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This does not happen on Linux (or any unices). The strings are properly null-terminated, especially since i'm using `std::string`.

- Socket Class: [[gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/c512f11e47d9a22dd0e1)]
- client.cpp: [[gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/617acb469c80cd3ef32c)]
- server.cpp: [[gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/10fffc3c9797dd7ff755)]

What am I doing wrong? Where does this extra data come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buffer.reserve(maxlen);
n = this->readInto(&buffer[0], maxlen);
if(n < 0)
{
     throw Socket::ReadError("ERROR reading from socket");
}
result = &buffer[0];
```

`result` does not know how many meaningful bytes are placed in the buffer. So it keeps reading bytes until it encounters a zero. That's how garbage gets into your output.

Comment: even after changing `result = &buffer[0]` to `result.append(&buffer[0], maxlen)`, the additional data keeps appearing...

Comment: ah, yes... I knew i was mixing up something :-) thank you :-)